# ffmpeg making gif from serially numbered images

Tags: ffmpeg

my files are named :

```
file1.png
file2.png
file3.png
....
file11.png
...
file123.png
...
file200.png
```

now I want to make a gif of these images. I tired with

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10  -pattern_type glob -i 'file*.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p growth.avi
```

but it does not work properly. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `'file*.png'` --> `'file%d.png'`

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to gif.

```
cd /home/user/Pictures && convert -delay 20 -loop 0 *.png result.gif
```

Based upon your output to video format (.avi), you can use the commands directly in console to output to video format

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -framerate 12 -i 'file*.png' -s 420x360 output.avi

ffmpeg -framerate 29 -i file%d.png output.avi
```

If you want to concat from file, first create file and give the location of the pictures. You can define duration in the file

Eg. Create imageList.txt in your picture folder. Put the location of picture like this.

```
file 'file4.png'
duration 2
file 'file5.png'
duration 2
file 'file6.png'
duration 3
file 'file7.png'
duration 2
file 'file8.png'
```

In console,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i imageList.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p asf.avi
```